# Iframe content not loading EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iframe, ejs

I know there are lots of questions about getting iframes to display content. I'm specifically struggling with iframe content displaying inconsistently while using Express. On one page this code works and the iframe displays the content fine, on another page for the same site the iframe doesn't show the content when I'm using the exact same code. Here is the code that I'm using for the iframe:

`<iframe src="<%=item.video%>" width="300" height="200"></iframe>`

I've tried moving it around to different sections of the page and that doesn't fix anything.

TIA

Comment: Without more specific debugging details all we can do is guess. Start by opening browser dev tools and inspect the generated `src` value is as expected. Check on network tab in dev tools to see what happens to the request. Look for network errors in console. This is a bit like saying ... *"my car started yesterday but not today...why?"*. [ask]

Comment: Thanks for explaining. When I looked at the src value it was empty. It just showed src=" " It's not displaying network errors on the console though. I'm not sure how to be more specific.

Comment: Sounds like `item.video` isn't what you think it is and you need to debug there